# PHP.ini location on El Capitan

Tags: php, apache, osx-elcapitan, php-ini

Simple question: where is the correct PHP.INI location in Mac OSX El Capitan?

I tried to update the one in */etc* folder, but nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have SSH access? Put this in the terminal and hit Enter: `php --ini`

Comment: php -i | grep additional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution

1. create php info file in your web folder

   ```
   <?php

    // Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
   phpinfo();

   ?>
   ```
2. open the file in browser
3. look for

> INFO_GENERAL  1   The configuration line, php.ini location, build date,
>   Web Server, System and more.

Taken from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

---

Another option is to use

```
<? php_ini_loaded_file(); ?>
```

Comment: phpinfo() says my php.ini is on 'etc' folder. But in this folder i have lots of files like php.ini-5.2-previous, php.ini.default, php.ini.default-previous and so on, but i DON'T have a file called simply 'php.ini'. What i'm missing here ?

Comment: try this instead `<? php_ini_loaded_file(); ?>`

Comment: I simply created the php.ini file and it worked, thanks !

Comment: <? php_ini_loaded_file(); ?> returns bool(false)

Answer (score 20):

The default location on OSX El Capitan and macOS Sierra is `/etc/php.ini`

But if that file doesn't exist, php will use `/etc/php.ini.default`. Don't forget to create a copy if you want to make changes:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Also, php will scan `/Library/Server/Web/Config/php` dir for additional .ini files

Restart Apache if you made any changes:

```
$ sudo apachectl -k restart
```

**Note:** if you install PHP7, this location will change to
`/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini`

Comment: Cheers! - this gem seems lost amongst a lot ofther SO  advice that didn't work for me....

Answer (score 19):

i know three ways:

1. php -i | grep php.ini
2. php --ini
3. create php file with following line: `<?php phpinfo();` and open the file in the browser

Answer (score 3):

Strange thing that phpinfo() does not display the file location, but here it is:
**/etc/php.ini.default**

Comment: It's actually possible that PHP is running without a php.ini file and is just running off defaults. If you copy /etc/php.ini.default to /etc/php.ini and restart Apache it will display /etc/php.ini as the Loaded Configuration File.

Answer (score 1):

```php
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$output = ob_get_clean();
preg_match("/(Loaded Configuration File => )([\/\w.]+\.ini)/i", $output, $matches);

echo $matches[2];
```

In my case I got:

`/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

This is a polished version of "Simple solution", someone posted before

1. create php info file in your web folder
2. `<?php phpinfo();?>`
3. open the file in browser
4. look for *php.ini*